# How to find iOS elements with a Appium Java Client?

Tags: java, appium-ios

Can't seem to either find the right element or I am trying to coerce the returned element into the wrong type. Looking for the correct syntax to find a button to tap it. I am working with an iOS simulator build, Appium, running test with a Java Client.

## AppTest.Java

```java
  @Test (enabled=true) public void myFirstTest() throws InterruptedException {
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

**IOSElement button = driver.findElement(MobileBy.AccessibilityId("UIA_upsellPage_third_button"));**
```

## Output

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Returned value cannot be converted to WebElement: {element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf=28000000-0000-0000-61D4-000000000000, ELEMENT=28000000-0000-0000-61D4-000000000000}
Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T15:28:36.4Z'
System info: host: 'C02R91M5G8WLMBP', ip: '2601:645:8002:1391:0:0:0:5d42%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.6', java.version: '12.0.1'
Driver info: driver.version: IOSDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:378)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:62)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.findElement(IOSDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.FindsByAccessibilityId.findElementByAccessibilityId(FindsByAccessibilityId.java:31)
    at io.appium.java_client.MobileBy$ByAccessibilityId.findElement(MobileBy.java:288)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:58)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.findElement(IOSDriver.java:1)
    at com.media.automation.iphone_automation_1.AppTest.myFirstTest(AppTest.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to class org.openqa.selenium.WebElement (java.util.HashMap is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.openqa.selenium.WebElement is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:376)
    ... 35 more
```

Expected Result:
Should return an element that can be tapped with a method to mimic a button press.

Actual Result: `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Returned value cannot be converted to WebElement: {element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf=28000000-0000-0000-61D4-000000000000, ELEMENT=28000000-0000-0000-61D4-000000000000}`

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate simulator with safari browser for web view app or you can use appium studio for native app

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your client is **out of date**.

Make sure you use the latest stable appium-java-client library, which is [7.0.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client/7.0.0)

And **do not include selenium-java dependency explicitly**, it is already coming in Appium.

And double check the Appium server version, **1.13.0** has been recently [released](https://github.com/appium/appium/releases).